# How can I install a github plugin into my xamarin forms solution? (VS Mac 2017)

Tags: c#, github, plugins, xamarin.forms

I just started coding in c# with Xamarin Forms and I wanted to know how I could install a plugin that I downloaded from GitHub. I searched for tutorials to install the plugin but I have not found anything about VS 2017 for mac. I tried to add the file manually but I had no success.

I have Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.

Comment: which specific plugin is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using Connectivity Plugin by **James Montemagno**

Github Plugin : [ConnectivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin)

- Open your Project and right click on Packages and select add package

If you are using .NET 2 you can do it this way

[image: Packages]

- Search for **Xam.Plugin.Connectivity** I found the name here (plugins normally have a link on their github branch)

Nuget : [Xam.Plugin.Connectivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity)

- Once found you can mark it and click on "Add Package"

[image: Packages]

- Once Added you will have to do the same process in your Android and IOS projects (its exactly the same process)
- And that's how to add a plugin :) ... If you want to get the plugin to work feel free to go through the plugin sample code [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin/tree/master/samples)
- don't forget to read **DOCUMENTATION** before posting a question