# Nuget packages for xamarin.forms in mac in visual studio

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

hi can someone please tell me where can I find nuget packages in xamarin.forms in mac I can see a folder with name packages in xamarin.ios in mac but In xamarin.forms I am not able to see any such folder to download nuget packages .

Comment: is your XF project a PCL, a shared project, or a netstandard project?

Comment: Related to an answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50463230/1752562) :)

Answer (score 0):

.nuget folder will be in /Users/UserName/.nuget/packages

You can use Finder->Go->Go to Folder-> "~/.nuget/packages"